# What can I do instead of [sic]?

Tags: writing-style, quotations

I have a quote that has a misplaced "to":

... they will put you to back to sleep ...

It seems like I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place. I can either:

- Just delete the mistaken "to" (then I would be deliberately misquoting them)
- Put [sic] next to it (which looks unbelievably pedantic, especially since they  write better than I do)

Is there a way around this?

Comment: maybe it was : they will put you two back to sleep

Comment: In this universe, I see only 3 things you could possibly do regarding the mistake - **(1)** *Leave it there* **(2)** *Correct it with [sic]* **(3)** *Correct it without sic* .. I don't see how any other 'ways around this' exist.

Comment: @ZafarS footnote?

Comment: @Lucas That would garner more attention. I don't see why you can't just correct it, it is a trivial mistake anyway.

Comment: @ZafarS that is what I did (I think, it was almost a year ago now).

Comment: @Lucas silly me, didn't notice, sorry.

Comment: @ZafarS I all fairness I had not accepted an answer indicating it (as I should have).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In its section on *Quotations and Dialogue: Permissible changes to punctuation, capitalization, and spelling*, the Chicago Manual of Style recommends:

> Obvious typographic errors may be corrected silently (without comment
>   or *sic*; see 13.59), unless the passage quoted is from an older work
>   or a manuscript source where idiosyncrasies of spelling are generally
>   preserved. If spelling and punctuation are modernized or altered for
>   clarity, readers must be so informed in a note, in a preface, or
>   elsewhere.

The choice is yours: make the correction and move on, or correct the text and flag it with a footnote[1].

However, the example you cite apparently isn't from an ancient manuscript, and your correction isn't modernizing it or altering it for clarity, so I would simply make the correction without comment.

> [1] Like this one.

Comment: I saw "Chicago Manual of Style" mentioned on Wikipedia. Do you know what kind of publication it is aimed at?

Comment: Its [subtitle](http://amzn.com/0226103897) is "The Essential Guide for Writers, Editors, and Publishers." It's intended to be a general reference for standard writing.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, you could also:

- paraphrase the quote (still source it, but don't put quotes) (e.g. The author contends they will put you back to sleep)
- make your own edits inside the quote (e.g. "they will put you ... back to sleep")
- just ignore it (e.g. "they will put you back to sleep[1]") and make the clarification in the footnote

Comment: I can't really do the first, the second is doable but looks like I've skipped a whole chunk of text.

Comment: The last one looks like the one - I love footnotes

Answer (score 2):

If the error isn't relevant to the topic at hand, I don't think there's any harm in silently correcting it. Footnoting it just to say "there was a typo in the original" seems twice as intrusive as "[sic]".