# How do I properly use [sic] for a phrase? Or do I use it at all?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The actual sentence I am quoting is:

> Company A will provide regular communications to Company B on the status of level of effort in comparison the projected monthly amounts contained in our contract.

Obviously there is a word missing.  This is how I think that sentence should be quoted:

> Company A will provide regular communications to Company B on the status of level of effort in comparison (to) [sic] the projected monthly amounts contained in our contract.

Is this even close?  I am just not sure.

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24750/how-do-you-quote-a-passage-that-has-used-sic-mistakenly

Answer (score 11):

The term *[sic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sic)* indicates "that an incorrect or unusual spelling, phrase, punctuation or meaning in the quote has been reproduced verbatim from the original".  As you have not reproduced the quote verbatim – you interpolated *(to)* – it would be wrong to also add *sic*.  See [How do you quote a passage that has used '[sic]' mistakenly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24750), [What can I do instead of [sic]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57951), and [The usage of "sic" in writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28935) for additional *sic* advice.

When you interpolate or modify material in a quote, enclose the addition or modification in square brackets, as in example below.  See [What is the proper use of [square brackets] in quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2271) and [How to add contextualizing text to a quotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14300) for discussion of brackets.

> Company A will provide regular communications to Company B on the status of level of effort in comparison [to] the projected monthly amounts contained in our contract.

Answer (score 5):

Only use [[sic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic)] when you don't change the original.

So copy the original, and place [sic] near the mistake:

> Company A will provide regular communications to Company B on the status of level of effort in comparison the projected monthly amounts [sic] contained in our contract.

However, the preferred option (particularly when the error is slight) is to leave the [sic] on the shelf and quietly correct the quote, using square brackets:

> Company A will provide regular communications to Company B on the status of level of effort in comparison [to] the projected monthly amounts contained in our contract.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to add a word or words to quote to correct a grammar error, etc, you do not use "[sic]". Rather, you put your added words in square brackets. In this case:

> Company A will provide regular communications to Company B on the status of level of effort in comparison [to] the projected monthly amounts contained in our contract.

Comment: Except that the additional word should be [with], not [to].

Comment: @Murphy I believe both "comparison with" and "comparison to" are routinely used. Google ngrams shows "with" as more popular but plenty of "to"s out there. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comparison+with%2Ccomparison+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomparison%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomparison%20to%3B%2Cc0 Both seem equally semantically valid to me.